# Exchange 2010 Scenario

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010

Advice Wanted.
We have two exchange 2010 servers with limited drive space on both.  We're going to purchase a server with far more space to create a DAG and have that as the primary server.

For those that have done similar is it difficult to add an additional exchange server and modify routing and transport?

Comment: What's going to happen if the primary server goes down and the mailbox database fails over to one of the existing servers? A new server with more disk space doesn't resolve the problem of too little disk space on the existing servers.

Comment: As phrased, your question is basically "is it difficult?". Well, that might depend on whether you know how to do it or not.  :-)

Comment: `Advice Wanted` - ok, ditch both Exchange 2010 servers, and go to Exchange Online and stop concerning yourself with routing/transports/DAGs. :)

Answer (score 3):

As Joeqwerty pointed out, this is a REALLY bad idea.  The idea of a DAG is so that in the event one of your severs has issues, you have a redundant server(s) to host the active copies of the databases.  If your primary server has more drive space available than the other DAG servers, you will eventually run into a case where your database files are larger than the drive space available on one or more of the "secondary" DAGs.  Your system would not be redundant at all.

If you are going to have an active/passive database setup then the servers should be identical in resources.